# Is it okay for me to freely edit meta FAQ entries?

Tags: discussion, meta-faq

Let's say I've found some missing information or something otherwise relevant that should go into the FAQ.

Is it considered acceptable that I (i.e. not a moderator on Stack Overflow or a Stack Exchange employee) edit the information directly into the [faq](/questions/tagged/faq) entry? Should I post a meta question to discuss it first?

Is there some clear guideline or procedure for FAQ editing?

Comment: On meta, when dealing with network-wide policies and stuff, you're at par with SO mods (they just have some shiny tools which you don't). Broadening it a bit, mods are at par with normal users on meta as well, unless it comes to (a) an executive decision on their own child meta, or (b) an "official" response on another meta.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Anything you edit will be bumped. So if you mess up, someone will fix it (and/or call you out).

So yes. Do whatever you want.

Most of the FAQs are kept up-to-date by non-moderators anyway.